# Where is the code for the "Dense" function in keras?

Tags: keras

I am trying to learn keras, and I keep coming across the `Dense` function, but I can't for the life of me find the source code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is the source code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py/#L765

---

The `Dense()` call creates a `Layer`, that you can add to your models.

The first parameter is the number of units/cells you want in this layer.
Everything else will be automatic, such as weight creation, output calculation, gradient descent, etc.

As a learner, you should probably not dive into the source code now, it's better to understand that it's a layer and it performs the operation:

```
inputs x weights + biases
```

Where the weights and biases are automatically created based on the number of units and the dimension of the inputs.

The best place to learn how to use Dense layers is the keras documentation:

https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense